# ForwardRef with refObject

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have using forwardRef with Input functional componet.

I want to set ref.current.value = "0"; for passed ref , but React.Ref got any props.

Is there are way to get passed ref as a React.RefObject instead of React.Ref?

```
const Input = forwardRef((props: InputProps, ref?: React.Ref<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const onChageHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      //want to do
      if (ref.current) {
        ref.current.value = "0";
      }
  };

  return (
    <Column vertical="center">
      {props.label && <label>{props.label}</label>}
      <input
        ref={ref}
        disabled={props.disabled}
        value={props.value === defaultNumberValue ? props.defaultDisplayValue || props.value : props.value}
        onChange={onChageHandler}
      />
    </Column>
  );
});
```

Please let me know if you need more info thanks.

Comment: What is your motivation to set the input.value to 0 in the onChange event handler?

Comment: You can not use the forwarded ref that you got from the parent component, since it may be null or it may be a function. Instead you need to use `useRef` to create a local copy. Combining `useRef` and `forwardRef` is complicated, please look at this answer for examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76485900/2100372