# Can't access ref.current using React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

Alright, I've read through every single thread and Github issue on this and couldn't find a real answer to why we can't `console.log(ref.current)` this on Typescript.

```
function App() {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


const Parent = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>(({}, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={ref}/>
    </div>
  );
});

export default Parent;




const Child = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement | null, IProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    console.log(ref.current)
    return <div ref={ref}>Hello World</div>;
  }
);
export default Child;
```

I understand that `ref` can be null thats why it makes sense to `console.log(ref?.current)` but I dont understand why we can't access the `current` even with an `if` statement.[image]

Comment: where are you using the `Child` component?

Comment: @Shan sorry, just fixed it up. check Parent component

Comment: Is this answer solve your problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238716/using-ref-current-in-react-forwardref

Comment: @RitikBanger I dont know if that answer is outdated, but its not working anymore

Comment: In your parent component, use (ref as MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>).current

Comment: @RitikBanger not working

Comment: @RitikBanger Actually, that did the trick. If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assert the ref, use `ref as MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>` as it is not necessary for every ref to have the current property.

In your parent component, use `(ref as MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>).current`

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the the DOM node until it is mounted. Use useEffect hook to check after mount.

```
const Child = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement | null, IProps>(
    (props, ref) => {

        useEffect(()=>{
          console.log(ref.current)
      },[])
      
      return <div ref={ref}>Hello World</div>;
    }
  );
```

Comment: still getting the same error!